# Embed webview containing login with GG in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm trying to embed a website with the GG login function into the Flutter app, but after logging in, the web view opens to a blank page and doesn't open to my main page. Is there any way I can handle this issue?

[image]

This is log of Webview

```
[GETX] Reader ConsoleLog - Type.DEBUG - 2023/10/31 14:50:10:175 - InAppWebviewControlState - build : Start load: https://www.linkedin.com/
[GETX] Reader ConsoleLog - Type.DEBUG - 2023/10/31 14:50:10:958 - InAppWebviewControlState - build : Stop load: https://www.linkedin.com/
[GETX] Reader ConsoleLog - Type.DEBUG - 2023/10/31 14:50:13:459 - InAppWebviewControlState - build : Start load: https://accounts.google.com/gsi/select?client_id=990339570472-k6nqn1tpmitg8pui82bfaun3jrpmiuhs.apps.googleusercontent.com&auto_select=true&ux_mode=popup&ui_mode=card&context=signin&as=69LRHm7bnj0QjZ2fw4Wbgw&channel_id=047703d54f2e330e84da2bc533ac3f0f36d31bf87fbc80cf98e10c3ff281366d&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com
[GETX] Reader ConsoleLog - Type.DEBUG - 2023/10/31 14:50:13:649 - InAppWebviewControlState - build : Stop load: https://accounts.google.com/gsi/select?client_id=990339570472-k6nqn1tpmitg8pui82bfaun3jrpmiuhs.apps.googleusercontent.com&auto_select=true&ux_mode=popup&ui_mode=card&context=signin&as=69LRHm7bnj0QjZ2fw4Wbgw&channel_id=047703d54f2e330e84da2bc533ac3f0f36d31bf87fbc80cf98e10c3ff281366d&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com
```